# White Square Flashes Briefly in Corner - Chrome, Scrollbar-related?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, scrollbar

This is odd:

A small white square will briefly flash into the upper-left corner of my browser window when I refresh a page using Chrome 11 on OS X.

I noticed the white box appears as the scrollbar renders.

As a test, I set overflow-y:hidden on the html element.

Sure enough, the white box no longer flashed as I refreshed the page.

Anybody know what would be causing this?

Here's a 32kb Quicktime:

http://ge.tt/33gTOk7

Comment: It sounds like you have a reduced test case: if this behavior appears in the latest dev channel as well, please file a bug at http://new.crbug.com/ and we'll get it triaged into the right team's queue.

Comment: I'm have the same issue and its driving me nuts. Happens for me when I apply `html{overflow-y:scroll;}`.